# How to hide or show a rectangle based on a variable

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2011

I hope someone can help, the title says it all really but here's the in depth bit.

Running Excel 2011 on Mac

I would like to know how I can hide or show a rectangle based on the variable for example

I have a variable in a1 that is a simple case of a link to another cell so the contents of a1 are =f20

If there is something in f20 then a1 will display it, if not a1 with show 0

If a1 shows 0 then I would like a rectangle to show that is currently hidden to cover up two pictures and a text box, rather than hiding the other items.

I don't mind this working from a button but would much prefer it to work as an integral part of the sheet.

I have already looked through the forums and videos and tbh they don't solve what I think could be something really simple, maybe i'm trying to over complicate this.

I hope this makes sense to someone

Please help, already had two sleepless nights trying to figure it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient answer, but it should do the trick:

```
Sub Hide_Rectangle()
    If Range("A1").Value = "0" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 1")).Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    ElseIf Range("A1").Value <> "0" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 1")).Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
        Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    End If
End Sub
```

Replace "Rectangle 1" with the shape name, and the rest should work.